# htaccess 301 permanent redirect using query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I'm trying to do a 301 with a query string.

I want to redirect

`www.mydomain.com/page1.php?id=12`

To

`www.mydomain.com/page2.php?id=12`

I've already tried this in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page_id=([0-9]+)$ 
RewriteRule ^page2.php?page_id=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I had changed the file name and named it wrong here in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine on    

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=\d+$ 
RewriteRule ^page1\.php$ /page2.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

Query string will be automatically copied over to new URL.